# CommunicationObjectFaulted when using a NamedPipe WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, named-pipes

Our .NET app uses 2 AppDomains. The secondary domain needs access to a Logger object that was created in the main appdomain.

This logger is exposed via a WCF service with a named pipe binding.

This is how i create the "client" for this service:

```
        private void InitLogger()
        {    
            if (loggerProxy != null)
            {
                Logger.Instance.onLogEvent -= loggerProxy.Log;
            }

            // Connect to the logger proxy.
            var ep = new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/app/log");
            var binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None);

            //Logger.Debug("Creating proxy to Logger object.");
            var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ILogProvider>(binding, ep);

            loggerProxy = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
            channelFactory.Faulted += (sender, args) => InitLogger();
            channelFactory.Closed += (sender, args) => InitLogger();

            Logger.Instance.onLogEvent += loggerProxy.Log;
        }
```

Recently we are getting random CommunicationObjectFaultedException - i suppose this occurs since the channel times out or due to some other reason that i am missing.

This is the reason i have added the handling of the *Closed* and *Faulted* events, which seem to not work properly (perhaps i have not used them appropriately).

EDIT: These events are on the Factory object as suggested, so this explains why they are not being raised.

My question is -- **how can i avoid these errors?**

Our scenario is we need to keep this channel open at all times throughout the application's lifetime, and the access to this Logger service is needed at all times, and shouldn't time out under any circumstance.

Is there any safe practice of handling this type of situation?

Answer (score 6):

Your code is currently handling Closed and Faulted events raised by the ChannelFactory, but it is the state of the Channel itself you need to worry about.

The ChannelFactory is an artefact which encapsulates the translation of the WCF service contract into an instance of the channel runtime: once you have successfully created your channel (`loggerProxy`), the closing of the ChannelFactory isn't going to affect communications via the channel - the events you are listening for are irrelevant to your problem.

State transitions of the **Channel** to Closed or Faulted will go unnoticed to this code, with the result that they will surface in Logger.Instance as exceptions thrown when `loggerProxy.Log` is invoked, and the event you are trying to log will be lost.

Instead of registering `loggerProxy.Log` directly as the event handler you should consider registering a wrapper function implementing an exception handler and retry loop around the call to loggerProxy.Log. The existing channel should be closed (or if that fails, aborted) in the exception handler, to ensure it is Disposed properly. The retry loop should reinitialise the channel and try the call again.

Comment: Thanks! is there some class from the BCL or open source implementation that you know that already provide this solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I'll comment on two things (i) the timeout and (ii) catching the Faulted events.

Firstly the timeout. By default, channels enter the faulted state if they haven't had a communication during the default time period (around 10 minutes). You can either poke the channel frequently with a recurring event, or reset the timeout to something large. I do the latter as follows:

```
    NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();

    // Have to set the receive timeout to be big on BOTH SIDES of the pipe, otherwise it gets faulted and can't be used.
    binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;

    DuplexChannelFactory<INodeServiceAPI> pipeFactory =
       new DuplexChannelFactory<INodeServiceAPI>(
          myCallbacks,
          binding,
          new EndpointAddress(
             "net.pipe://localhost/P2PSN.Node.Service.Pipe"));
```

myCallbacks is an instance of a class that deals with callbacks in the duplex pipe and INodeServiceAPI is the interface that describes my API.

Secondly you're right in the the factory events will not be fired. You can catch the events on the channel itself. I use the following code.

```
    proxy = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
    if (proxy is IClientChannel)
    {
        (proxy as IClientChannel).Faulted += new EventHandler(this.proxy_Faulted);
    }
```

Not pleasant, but something I picked up from StackOverflow elsewhere that works. You must include System.ServiceModel to pick up the IClientChannel interface.

HTH.

Comment: Setting ReceiveTimeout on the proxy side to MaxValue doesn't mean that sending a message and receiving NO MESSAGE would indefinitely block the client side ?

Comment: Worth checking out. I'm using the above as one side of an inter-process pipe between a windows service and a windows form app that manages it. You could leave the timeout alone, catch the Fault, take everything down and create a new channel... but that seems extreme. Certainly a recurrent quick ping every so often may be more approppriate for application where a DoS may be attempted.

Comment: DoS is not a concern here. I am doing an inter app-domain communication. This is not a service at all, just an easy-glue for taping together method calls between both app domains.